# Consumo de dados de internet usando Vue.Js ou similares

Tags: javascript, vue.js, front-end

Bom dia,
Tenho uma aplicação em Vue, onde o nav superior e lateral estão estáticos, e o conteúdo (body) é carregado conforme as requisições feitas nos links do nav. O Vue acelera muito a utilização, carregando só o centro, mas isso significa que o consumo de dados de internet é menor por só estar carregando o body? Ou ele carrega tudo novamente sem que a gente perceba?

Exemplo: Se existirem dois sistemas iguais visualmente, um escrito em html tradicional, e outro utilizando o Vue.Js, o vue consumiria menos internet? (sabendo que o html carrega novamente a página completa a cada requisição)

Answer (score 0):

de maneira geral, uma pagina SPA após está carregada vai consumir menos banda que uma aplicação tradicional (Multi Page), porem dependendo de como esteja a implementação, você terá que baixar uma grande quantidade de dados na primeira requisição. Porem é possível contornar este problema utilizando algumas técnicas.

[**Lazy Loading**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk)

A ideia aqui é que o componente referenciado pela rota seja carregado sobre demanda. Então ao invés de fazemos isto.:

```
import SomePage from 'pages/SomePage'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/some-page',
    component: SomePage
  }
]
```

podemos declarar a rota da seguinte forma.:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/some-page',
    component: () => import('pages/SomePage')
  }
]
```

[**PWA**](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)

PWA veio parar tonar a experiencia na WEB o mais próximo possível de se está utilizando um aplicativo. E uma aplicação PWA deve ser.:

- **Progressiva** - Funcionar bem em qual quer browser.
- **Responsiva** - Se adaptar a qual quer tela
- **Indepedente de Rede** - Funcionar mesmo estando offline
- **Parecer com um Aplicativo** - A experiencia de uso deve ser parecida a de um aplicativo instalado.
- **Sempre Atualizado** - não precisa de comentario.
- **Segura** - Sempre utilizar HTTPS
- **Indexável** - Permitir a indexação por paginas de pesquisa (Google, Binq, etc).
- **Engajável** - Permitir que o continue facilmente uma tarefa ou seja notificado caso algo novo apareça (Push).
- **Instalável** - Permitir adicionar um atalho na area de trabalho.
- **Compartilhável** - Compartilhar apenas usando um Link.

Para se chegar a este resultado, é preciso usar tudo que está ao nosso alcance, [`Services Workers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) para manter a aplicação sempre atualizada, [`Push API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) para notificar o Usuario, [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ou [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) para armazenar dados localmente (conteúdo dinâmico) e [`Cache API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) para armazenar `assets` (imagens, fontes, etc).

[**SSR**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)

Basicamente é permitir que as suas paginas possam ser renderizadas também no servidor. como estamos falando de `VueJS`, você terá de usar o [`Nuxt.js`](https://nuxtjs.org)

[**Quasar Framework**](https://quasar-framework.org)

Acredite, você pode utilizar tudo de uma vez, `Lazy Loading`, `PWA`, `SSR` e ainda fazer deploy para `Android` e `iOS` usando `Cordova` e `Windows`, `Mac`, `Linux` usando o `Electron`, e o `Quasar Framework` vai lhe ajudar a manter todos estes mundos unidos sem criar um pandemônio.